# data insert failing when trying to insert data using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am trying to insert data in a table using linq to SQL and jquery but its failing, cant find why.

Here is how I am doing:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveHours(string descType, string wrkType, decimal hours)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();

        Project hrs = new Project ();

        {
            hrs.descType = descType;
            hrs.wrkType = wrkType;
            hrs.hours= (decimal)hours;
        }

        db.Project.InsertOnSubmit(hrs);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        return Json(new { message = "Hours Saved" });
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

$("#SaveHours").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var link = '/Project/SaveHours';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { hours: $("#HoursWorked").val(),
            descType: $("#Description").val(),
            wrkType: $("#WorkType").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });

    });
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<UI.Models.vwProject>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="Description" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Work Type
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="WorkType" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Hours Worked
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="HoursWorked" type="text"/>            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="SaveHours" type="button" >Save</button>
        </td>        
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Am I missing something here?
Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE [Project]
(
    ProjectKey      INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    descType        VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    wrkType         VARCHAR(10)         NULL,
    hours           NUMERIC(5,2)        NULL
)
```

Comment: What is your Project table structure?  What is the exception thrown by Linq-to-SQL

Comment: @RobertSlaney I have updated my question above with Table script, and exception

Comment: Is it anything as basic as the order of the elements in the data that jQuery is posting? This is a guess, maybe your exception (which I can't see) would prove me wrong.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake I got it to work, I hadnt defined a primary key in the table yet! so couldnt perform CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT at Controller:

```
  ...
 if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
     return Json(new { message = "Hours Saved"  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  ...
```